# Reasons for better debugging experience for generated IAsyncStateMachine

Tags: .net, async-await

The state machine (`IAsyncStateMachine`), generated by .NET compiler for async/await method, is a struct in release mode, for performance reasons, and it is a class in debug mode to give a better debugging experience : which are the exact technical reasons that make this "better experience" ?

(I don't know if this is true for all compiler versions, but this is not relevant).

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons is that value types (which a `struct` is) are passed around by value (copied) while for reference types what is passed around is "pointer".

This means that the debugger can old a referenece to the state machine and controll its lifetime.

Comment: This can be a reason (following the Occam's razor :) ), but debugger could use the same technique adopted in release mode to use the value type.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC this is to support EnC (edit-and-continue). Remember that things like local variables are stored on the `IAsyncStateMachine` implementation. If the user adds a new local variable to their async method, the debugger needs to add a corresponding field to the `IAsyncStateMachine`.

If the `IAsyncStateMachine` is a struct, there might be a copy of it on the `async` method's stack (if we haven't hit the first `await` yet), there might be a copy in a box somewhere on the heap, abd potentially in some other place as well? I imagine that tracking down all of these copies and modifying them appropriately is harder / impossible, compared to modifying a single instance of a class on the heap.